# Vue3- [Provide and Inject] when data changes ,not do visual update ,I use filter( ) to del an item in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am test `provide and inject` method. I put `datas`, `del-function` in parent to provide, I put dynamic render in child using `v-for='data' in datas`...

The goal I want to implement is: when I press the "delete button"=>`del-function` in child, then `datas` in parent get an item deleted , and `datas` in parent `provide` get updated.

### Then child get new `datas` to do visual update. `v-for` re-render. [!!!]

But when I press  the "delete button" , `datas` updated ,but visually ,no one get deleted.

[v-for rendered cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/669Qy.png)

```
// parent vue file 
<template>
  <Reslist/>
</template>

<script>

import Reslist from './components/ResList.vue'

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
     Reslist
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      datas: this.datas,
      delData: this.delData,
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "wawa",
          age: "18",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "wmmmfwa",
          age: "1128",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    delData(id) {
      console.log('delete-id ='+ id);
      const newDatas = this.datas.filter( element => element.id !== id);
      this.datas = newDatas;
      console.log( this.datas);

    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

---

```
// child vue file
<template>
   <div v-for='data in datas' :key="data.name">
        <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{data.age}}</p>
        <button @click='delData(data.id)'>delete</button>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    inject:['datas','delData']
}
</script>
<style scoped>
div{
    width: 18.75rem;
    margin: 1.25rem auto;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
</style>
```

I know how to use prop to pass data to child. I just want to know why [provide and inject] don't work?? In [provide],I already [datas = this.datas] , does my logic have mistakes?

Answer (score 5):

Good night, Bro!

I found a solution using computed props...

Hope its helpful!

**Parent Vue File**

```
<template>
  <Reslist/>
</template>

<script>
import Reslist from './ResList.vue'
import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity'
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
     Reslist
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      datas: computed(() => this.datas),
      delData: this.delData,
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "wawa",
          age: "18",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "wmmmfwa",
          age: "1128",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    delData(id) {
      console.log('delete-id ='+ id);
      const newDatas = this.datas.filter( element => element.id !== id);
      this.datas = newDatas;
      console.log(this.datas);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**Child File**

```
<template>
   <div v-for='data in datas' :key="data.name">
        <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{data.age}}</p>
        <button @click='delData(data.id)'>delete</button>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  inject:['datas','delData']
}
</script>
<style scoped>
div{
    width: 18.75rem;
    margin: 1.25rem auto;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
</style>
```

**Configuring Main.js To Accept Computed prop.**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.unwrapInjectedRef = true
app.mount('#app')
```

The information for this config : https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity

Answer (score 3):

Your injected data is not working in a reactive way, and per the [Vue.js Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity), in order for injected data to do this, you must provide it as a *computed* property by wrapping it in a `computed()` function:

[image]

Which states:

> ## Working with Reactivity
>
> In order to make injections reactively linked to the provider, we need to provide a computed property using the computed() function

In your case, it might look like this:

```js
  provide() {
    return {
      datas: computed(() => this.datas),
      delData: this.delData,
    };
  },
```

---

Having said this, Vue is always undergoing updates, enhancements and fixes, and in order for this to work fully, *temporarily*, you must add an additional config to your application:

[image]

Which states:

> ## Temporary Config Required
>
> The above usage requires setting `app.config.unwrapInjectedRef = true` to make injections automatically unwrap computed refs. This will become the default behavior in Vue 3.3 and this config is introduced temporarily to avoid breakage. It will no longer be required after 3.3.

In code, this could look like so:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'

const app = createApp(App);
app.config.unwrapInjectedRef = true;

app.mount('#app')
```